# Find text, then insert linebreak and some php code across multiple files

Tags: linux, grep, sed

I have a certain php code comment that appears in about 75 files across several users. This command succsessfully locates it. (I didn't bother looking for the double slashes because I wasn't sure about escaping them and they really don't matter for this match.)

```
grep -l -r "calls the myfunc() function" /home/*/public_html
```

After I find it, I need to add a line break and some more php code like

```
if($my_return_var===false){echo "<b>THERE WAS AN ERROR</b>";}
```

I also need to do similar, like

```
grep -l -r "include('path/to/my/file.php')" /home/*/public_html
```

and then insert BEFORE it

```
"$my_return_var="
```

Searching Google, I found that grep piped to sed is probably the way to go, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Can anyone help?
By the way, this q/a is probably close, but still a little over my head. [How to replace a text string in multiple files in Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/70939/how-to-replace-a-text-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can do inserts and appends when it sees a pattern:

```
grep -l -r "calls the myfunc() function" /home/*/public_html |
xargs sed -i '/calls the myfunc() function/a\
if($my_return_var===false){echo "<b>THERE WAS AN ERROR</b>";}
'

grep -l -r "include('path/to/my/file.php')" /home/*/public_html |
xargs sed -i "/include('path\\/to\\/my\\/file.php')"'/i\
"$my_return_var="
'
```

Comment: I clicked on accept because your first one worked. I am having difficulty with the second one. I'll post details in a sec. @glenn

Comment: @TecBrat, sorry, forgot to put the pattern in the sed command. Plus you have to do some quoting tricks. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! I started to say I might never have figured it out, but that's stretching it a bit, but you sure saved me a lot of time. The second one adds a line break, right after the inserted text, that I didn't expect, but I think I can live with it. Can we omit that? (the line break before the append on the first one was desireable, so I'll leave that alone.)

Comment: @TecBrat, put the closing single quote on the previous line to get rid of that extra newline.

Comment: By the way, I just went from testing to the real thing and it went very smoothly. If I could upvote a second time, I would. :-)

Comment: I actually put it all on one line, so I'm not sure why I got the extra newline, but I'm not worried about it. I already implemented it and the PHP parses correctly anyway.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: **make a backup!**

Second thing: **make a backup!**

Since I know perl much better than python, I'd use the perl solution.

Remember that "\n" is a newline in perl, so, something like:

```
grep -l -r "calls the myfunc() function" /home/*/public_html |xargs perl -pi -e 's/(calls the myfunc() function;)/$1\n if($my_return_var===false){echo "<b>THERE WAS AN ERROR</b>";}/'
```

I have obviously not tested this, and that's a brute force way to do it (and assumes a bunch of things, e.g., the grep doesn't return filenames with spaces in them and so on).  If your search/replace patterns contain "/", you can use an alternative delimiter to your pattern, e.g., `s?(calls the myfunc() function;)?$1\n if($my_return_var===false){echo "<b>THERE WAS AN ERROR</b>";?'`

Comment: for the second half, do I have to do escapes, like this: `...|xargs perl -pi -e 's/(include(\'path/to/my/file.php\');)/\$my_return_var=$1;}/'`

Comment: Oh, I probably needed more escapes for the parens in the patterns.  Realistically, I probably wouldn't try to do a one-liner.  I'd write a perl script for this.

Comment: +1 for Make a backup! Make a backup!